# If you have two distinct Data Source Connections in ColdFusion with the same settings do they share the same pool?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have created 2 distinct data source connections (to MS SQL Server 2008) in the ColdFusion Administrator that have exactly the same settings except for the actual name of the connection. My question is will this create two distinct connection pools or will they share one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will have different pools. The pools are defined at the data source level and you have two distinct data sources as far as ColdFusion is concerned. Why would you have two different data sources with the exact same settings? I guess if you wanted to force them to use different connection pools. I can't think of a reason why though.

I found this page that documents [how database connections are handled in ColdFusion](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/database-connections-handled-coldfusion.html). Note that the "Maintain Database Connections" setting is set for each data source.

Here is the section related to connection pooling from that page (in case it goes away):

> **If the "Maintain Database Connections" is set for a data source, how does ColdFusion Server maintain the connection pool?**
>
> When "Maintain Database Connections" is set for a data source, ColdFusion keeps the connection open after its first connection to the database. It does not log out of the database after this first connection. You can change this setting according to the instructions in step d above. Another setting in the ColdFusion Administrator, called "Limit cached database connection inactive time to X minutes," closes a "maintained" database connection after X inactive minutes. This setting is server wide and determines when a "maintained" connection is finally closed. You can modify this setting by going to the "Caching" tab within the ColdFusion Administrator. The interface for modifying the "Limit cached database connection inactive time to X minutes" looks like the following:
>
> [image]
>
> If a request is using a data source connection that is already opened, and another request to the data source comes in, a new connection is established. Since only one request can use a connection at any time, the simultaneous request will open up a new connection because no idle cached connections are available. The connection pool can increase up to the setting for simultaneous connections limit which is set for each data source. This setting, called, "Limit Connections," is in the ColdFusion Administrator. Click on one of the data source tabs and then click on one of your data sources. Click on "CF Settings" and put a check next to "Limit Connections" and enter a number in the sentence, "Enable the limit of X simultaneous connections." Please note that if you do not set this under the data source setting, ColdFusion Server will use the server wide "Simultaneous Requests" setting.
>
> At this point, there is a pool of two database connections that ColdFusion Server maintains. Each connection remains in the pool until either the "Connection Timeout" period is reached or exceeds the inactivity time. If neither of the first two options are implemented, the connections remain in the pool until ColdFusion is restarted.
>
> The "Connection Timeout" setting closes the connection and eliminates it from the pool whether or not it has been active or inactive. If the process is active, it will not terminate the connection. You can change this setting by going to "CF Settings" for your data source in the ColdFusion Administrator. Note: Only the "Cached database connection inactive time" setting will end the connection and eliminate it from the pool if it hasn't been used. You can also use the "Connection Timeout" to override the"Cached database connection inactive" setting as it applies only to a single data source, not all data sources.

Answer (score 1):

They have different pools.  Pooling is implemented by cf java code. (Or was that part in the jrun code.... ).  It doesn't use any jdbc based pooling. Cf10 could have switched to jdbc based pooling but I doubt it.

As a test

Set the 'verify connection' sql to wait-for delay '00:01:00' or similar (wait for 1 minute) on both pools. As pool access is single-threaded for each pool - including the time taken to run the verify - have 2 pages each accessing a different data source , request both. If they complete after 1 minute it's 2 pools, if one page takes 1 minute and the other takes 2 minutes - it's one pool

As a side note, if during this 1 minute verify you yank out the network cable (causing the jdbc socket to stay open forever waiting for a response  ) your thread pool is now dead and you need to restart CF

Answer (score 0):

Try to create temporary table with two different datasource, if you get error for second query  it use same pool and run perfectly file means different pool.